# Opencart 2.0 Category Specific Echo

Tags: php, mysql, opencart2.x

I am trying to achieve a category specific echo in Opencart 2.0 and somehow I could not get this to work. I am still a noob in PHP and OC is not making it any better!

I want a certain echo to generate, where if category is X then AAA, if Y then BBB, else CCC but how do I get OC2 to echo the category ID(X/Y/Z)? Also, a product can be in multiple categories, but not in X, Y or Z at the same time, so querying for product in the category table returns multiple line for the same product. E.g

```
product_id    category_id
1111          X
1111          D
1111          M
1112          Y
1112          D
1113          Z
```

I don't know if this sounds like just gibberish but any help is much appreciated.

Basically what I am trying to achieve is:

```
IF category = X 
THEN URL = /index.php?egg=1111

IF category = Y 
THEN URL = /index.php?meat=1111

IF category = Z 
THEN URL = /index.php?fish=1111
```

### EDIT

What I tried doing is this :

```
SELECT mv_product.product_id, mv_product_to_category.category_id FROM mv_product LEFT OUTER JOIN mv_product_to_category ON mv_product.product_id = mv_product_to_category.product_id WHERE mv_product_to_category.category_id IN(20,25,34)
```

What is technically does is queries the CategoryId for the particular productid and then check if this categoryid falls under x,y or z and then echo accordingly.

Is this a correct direction?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do this by following the Opencart's url helper,

Loop through your query result like below and form the href by using the url helper,

```
$url='';
foreach ($results as $result) {
    $path=$result['cat_id'];
    $this->data['products'][] = array(
        'product_id'  => $result['product_id'],
        'name'        => $result['name'],
        'description' => $result['description'],
        'href'        => $this->url->link('product/product', 'path=' . $path . '&product_id=' . $result['product_id'] . $url,'SSL')
   );
}
```

Pass the category id in the path param.Don't forget to enable seo url in your admin end.

Comment: Thanks for that, but I am unsure if that is what I want to achieve. It could easily be my lack of PHP knowledge that is the reason.

I am only looking to generate the URL variable parameter based on category ID. The other variants of the URL are generated using static url + $product_id

Comment: Mani, I was a little unsure of how to execute this. Like I said earlier, I am a noob. I have asked someone else to try this out and will post back as soon as I have an answer.